# Browser-specific SVG display issue

Tags: css, svg, amazon-s3

On the site http://expensebite.com, I have a logo on the top left that is an SVG with a fall-back to PNG. It doesn't behave as expected, and I cannot trace why (not sure how):
- Chrome 45.0.2454.101 on Win10: downloads the SVG, shows nothing at any resolution
- FF 40.0.3 on Win10: shows a grey box
- MS Edge 20.10240.16384.0 on Win10: shows the logo
- Safari 8.0.8 on MacBook: shows nothing

Why? How would I debug this?

Comment: Need to see code, svg can be iffy depending on how its inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVGs are being served with the wrong Content-type (MIME type).  They are being served as `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/svg+xml`.

Check your web server configuration.

You cen see for yourself what content type it is being served as, in your browser web tools -  "Net" (or "Network") tab.

Answer (score 1):

Your logo at `http://expensebite.com/images/logo.svg` is being served with an incorrect HTTP header, so the browser is interpreting it as a binary stream instead of as as an image. It is currently being served with the header

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

and to be used in an `object` tag it needs to be served instead with the proper SVG Content-Type header of

```
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
```

You will need to configure your server to serve the `svg` file using the correct content type headers, which is a process that will vary depending on what type of server software / hosting you are using.